# Broadcast Receiver for ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON not fired

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing and app which stream data from online, i have used Android MediaPlayer and AudioManager and everything working fine. I am stuck up in ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON to play / pause the player through headphone button.

> FYI, i have used all the way suggested in stackover, setPriority to
>   999 or 1000 or 10000 also register listener in android menifeast file etc.
>   but not result.

***BroadcarstReceiver File***

public class HeadSetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
    onHeadsetEventListener mCallback;


    public interface onHeadsetEventListener {
        void onHeadsetRemoved();

        void onHeadsetNextClicked();

        void onHeadsetPreviousClicked();

        void onHeadsetPlayPauseClicked();
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mCallback = (onHeadsetEventListener) context;


        // Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG  << Trigger as soon i plug and unplug the headphone..

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    mCallback.onHeadsetRemoved();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON ---- Not triggered even after register listener
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
            int action = event.getAction();
            Log.i("keycode", String.valueOf(keycode));
            Log.i("action", String.valueOf(action));
            //onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE  || keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK)
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    mCallback.onHeadsetPlayPauseClicked();
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT)
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    mCallback.onHeadsetNextClicked();
            if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS)
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    mCallback.onHeadsetPreviousClicked();

        }
    }
}
```

*** I have registered listener in MediaPlayerService.java - OnCreate() as
 follow***

```
headSetReceiver = new HeadSetReceiver();

IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
filter2.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
registerReceiver(playerRadioService.headSetReceiver,filter2);
```

***And also unregistered onDestroy as follow***

```
unregisterReceiver(headSetReceiver);
```

But i am not sure, what i am missing to implement and hence there is no result on this.

> LOGCAT

```
  --------- beginning of system
06-13 00:03:36.316 1192-1202/? D/BroadcastQueue: Add broadcastBroadcastRecord{30a21c3 u0 android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON} into (background/order), now header = BroadcastRecord{30a21c3 u0 android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON}, size = 1
06-13 00:03:36.318 1192-1202/? D/BroadcastQueue: Add broadcastBroadcastRecord{16bfa40 u0 android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON} into (background/order), now header = BroadcastRecord{30a21c3 u0 android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON}, size = 2
06-13 00:03:36.321 1192-1961/? V/BroadcastQueue: Finished with ordered broadcast BroadcastRecord{30a21c3 u0 android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON}, [background], remain = 1
06-13 00:03:36.324 1192-2185/? V/BroadcastQueue: Finished with ordered broadcast BroadcastRecord{16bfa40 u0 android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON}, [background], remain = 0
06-13 00:03:36.755 271-335/? D/phoneserver: rsrp[0]=97,rscp[0]=255,rxlev[0]=99 ind_str= 
                                            +CESQ: 99,99,255,255,22,97
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the receiver in your manifest file?

Comment: As per my knowledge, if you are registering the receiver dynamically as i did in onCreate(), no need to declare in manifest file..

Comment: Could you plz confirm, registering and declare are the same or different?